# How to run aws cli commands as a specific user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

Currently we are running 4 commands:

below two aws cli  commands in jenkins docker container:

```
sh 'aws cloudformation package  ...'
s3Upload()
```

Below two  aws cli commands in docker container:

```
aws s3 cp source dest
aws cloudformation deploy
```

To run these above 4 commands in docker container, `aws cli` derive access permissions from docker host( EC2 ) **which** assumes a **role** with policy having permissions ( to access s3 and create/update cloud formation stack).

---

But the **problem** with such solution is,

we have to assign this **role**(say `xrole`) to every EC2 that is running in each test environment. There are 3-4 test environments.

Internally, aws creates an adhoc user as `aws::sts::{account Id}::assumerole/xrole/i-112223344` and above 4 commands run on behalf of this user.

---

**Better solution** would be to create a user and assign the same  **role**(`xrole`) to this and run above 4 commands as this user.

But,

1) what is the process to create such user? Because it has to assume `xrole`...

2) how to run above 4 commands with this user?

Comment: The best practice is to use roles (EC2 instance profiles), not users (access keys). So your current approach is fine. You have to assign this instance profile to every EC2  instance you launch.

Comment: @erhanux but EC2 instance profile can have only one role, if you allocate EC2 through cloudformation template. Do you think mixing multiple policies in a single role may contradict each other? because EC2 is used for multiple purpose. Each test machine EC2 may have multiple tasks for which multiple different policies needed

Comment: @erhanux Throwing access key(user) in each EC2 isn't a better solution?

Comment: Create as many instance profiles as needed in that case. It is best to follow the principle of least privilege . Two servers can be assigned the same instance profile if they require the same set of permissions.

Comment: no, it is not. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html#use-roles

Comment: @erhanux so.. can we assign multiple instance profiles to single EC2 using cloudformation template?

Comment: no, you can instead create an instance profile to give all the required permissions. you can attach multiple policies to a single role.

Comment: @erhanux problem is having one instance profile with one role having multiple policies can contradict policy rules. Because, EC2 host can be used for various tasks. Policy1 can say read only access to s3 for task1 and policy 2 can say write only access to s3 for task2.but keeping this combination in a role within instance profile will give full access to s3, for both tasks. Isn't it?

Comment: @overexchange you can have role per task if you choose to use ECS

Comment: @MatusDubrava currently we have running environment with EC2. Am not sure what ECS mean?

Comment: @overexchange there is no contradiction. that is how IAM works. grant least privilege and specify resource-level permissions. e.g. rw for bucket-x, read-only for bucket-y...

Comment: @overexchange ECS is service that allows you to manage containers, it is still using EC2 instances but it provides you with enhanced management, such as role and SG per task instead of per instance.

Comment: @MatusDubrava can you provide reference on assigning roles to containers using ECS? Would like to know, How to process...

Comment: @overexchange see the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use roles, not users when working with EC2 instances. Users are necessary only when you need to grant permissions to applications that are running on computers outside of AWS environment (on premise). And even then, it is still best practice to grant this user permissions to only assume role which grants the necessary permissions.

If you are running all your commands from within containers and you want to grant permissions to containers instead of the whole EC2 instance then what you can do is to use ECS service instead of plain EC2 instances.

When using EC2 launch type with ECS, you have the same control over the EC2 instance but the difference is that you can attach role to a particular task (container) instead of the whole EC2 instance. By doing this, you can have several different tasks (containers) running on the same EC2 instance while each of them have only permissions that its needs. So if one of your containers needs to upload data to S3, you can create necessary role, specify the role in task definition and only that particular task will have those permissions. Neither other tasks nor the EC2 instance itself will be able to upload objects to S3.

Moreover, if you specify `awsvpc` networking mode for your tasks, each task will get its own ENI which means that you can specify Security Group for each task separately even if they are running on the same EC2 instance.

Here is an example of task definition using docker image stored in ECR and role called `AmazonECSTaskS3BucketRole`.

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "sample-app",
      "image": "123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aws-nodejs-sample:v1",
      "memory": 200,
      "cpu": 10,
      "essential": true
    }
  ],
  "family": "example_task_3",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/AmazonECSTaskS3BucketRole"
}
```

Here is documentation for [task definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197803/discussion-on-answer-by-matus-dubrava-how-to-run-aws-cli-commands-as-a-specific).

Comment: How to untilise a security aspect from API gateway? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57485799/3317808

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57963970/3317808  Authntication at docker artifacts level

Answer (score 1):

Applications running on the same host share the permissions assigned to the host through the instance profile. If you would like to segregate different applications running on the same instance due to security requirements, it is best to launch them on separate instances. 
Using access keys per application is not a recommended approach as access keys are long-term credentials and they can easily be retrieved when the host is shared.

It is possible to assign IAM roles to ECS tasks as suggested by the previous answer. However, containers that are running on your container instances are not prevented from accessing the credentials that are supplied through the instance profile. It is therefore recommended to assign minimal permissions to the container instance roles.

If you run your tasks in awsvpc network mode, then you can configure ECS agent to prevent a task from accessing the instance metadata. You should just set agent configuration variable, **ECS_AWSVPC_BLOCK_IMDS=true** and restart the agent.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that statement that it is recommended to use different hosts for different tasks? Also any AWS reference would be nice. According to AWS best practices you should use task roles, not access keys and you can freely run them on the same container instance.

Comment: I didn't mean tasks in the context of ECS but as two separate applications. Going to edit it.