# Inbuilt authentication mechanism - API gateway

Tags: authentication, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

API gateway has in-built functionality to perform authorization.

But the examples provided by awslabs have lambda hooked to API gateway, where lambda is authorizing as per this [code](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_lambda_request_auth/src/authorizer.js) for a below API gateway:

```
MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyLambdaRequestAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyLambdaRequestAuthorizer:
            FunctionPayloadType: REQUEST
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt MyAuthFunction.Arn
```

---

So, auth token provided by client is received by lambda and then authorised:

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  const token = event.queryStringParameters.auth.toLowerCase()

  ....

     switch (token) {
    case 'allow':
      return generateAuthResponse('user', 'Allow', methodArn)
    case 'deny':
      return generateAuthResponse('user', 'Deny', methodArn)
    default:
      return Promise.reject('Error: Invalid token') // Returns 500 Internal Server Error
  }
}
```

but this is not in-built authentication provided by API gateway.

How does API gateway provide in-built authentication?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

Create and Use Usage Plans with API Keys : In this method you can use API Keys to authenticate a user. follow this link : [API Keys method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-console.html)

**Solution 2 :**

You can AWS Amazon Cognito service for authentication. It is same as OKTA service. Follow this link : [Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-cognito.html)