# How to authenticate docker client commands in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, authentication, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

Below authentication can be implemented using certificates(client & server), for any human user using docker client that talks to docker daemon:

### [image]

But, jenkins pipeline also run docker commands to talk to docker daemon.

How to authenticate jenkins pipeline to run specific docker commands? where this pipeline is launched as jenkins slave container in AWS EC2 on every new commit in Git..... Does ECS cluster approach in launching pipeline task help in authentication?

Comment: you want to pull image from docker hub or AWS ECR?

Comment: @Adiii yes...we  also push image... we cannot anticipate the commands that a pipeline can run in future... we cannot restrict any developer to run specific comands unless you provide authentication.

Comment: Amazon ECR requires that users have allow permissions to the ecr:GetAuthorizationToken API through an IAM policy before they can authenticate to a registry and push or pull any images from any Amazon ECR repository. Amazon ECR provides several managed IAM policies to control user access at varying levels; for more information

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-pull-ecr-image.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run docker login from your jenkins script and store the secrets in jenkins config. You could also pre-install credentials on the machine as part of your build process. If you are talking about permissions to talk to the daemon, you have to give the jenkins user the appropriate permissions (usually add it to the docker group`

Comment: yes am talking about permissions to talk to the daemon... Can Jenkins container allow running docker commands without configuring a jenkins user and use AWS roles assigned to that jenkins container....

Comment: AWS IAM has nothing to do with Daemon permissions. For a local daemon, it is controlled with filesystem permissions on the docker socket. For a remote one, auth is set up with a client key-pair that has to be distributed.

Comment: Jenkins always has a user on the system- its jobs are run as that user (on whatever machine the executor happens to be running on). You can grant IAM permissions to the machine that the Jenkins user can use (as any other process), but those only apply to AWS resources. You could use that to allow you to login to an Elastic Container Registry- (`docker login`) ... but not to auth to an actual docker daemon anywhere.